# Solspace Calendar; list events by day but suppress output of days with no events

Tags: solspace-calendar

I have a client with an older EE (2.1.1) running Calendar 1.5.3.

They want an event list by day that doesn't display days with no events. I'm using this code at present:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" show_days="30" pad_short_weeks="n"} 
 {display_each_day}
  <div class="day_list">
   <h3 class="day">{day format="%l, %F %j"}</h3>
   {if day_event_total == 0}<p>No Events</p>{/if}
    {events}
     <p><a class="event_name" href="#">{event_title}</a> {event_start_date format="%g:%i %a"} - {event_end_date format="%g:%i%a"}</p>
    {/events}
  </div>
 {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Which essentially works aside from the fact that of course all days with no events display with the message. They're reasoning that there's no need to show a day if there's no event. Is there a way to do this?

MANY thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `{if day_event_total > 0} ... {/if}` conditional:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" show_days="30" pad_short_weeks="n"} 
 {display_each_day}
  <div class="day_list">
   {if day_event_total > 0}<h3 class="day">{day format="%l, %F %j"}</h3>{/if}
   {if day_event_total == 0}<p>No Events</p>{/if}
    {events}
     <p><a class="event_name" href="#">{event_title}</a> {event_start_date format="%g:%i %a"} - {event_end_date format="%g:%i%a"}</p>
    {/events}
  </div>
 {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

If you really wanted to show *nothing* on days with no events, you could also remove the `{if day_event_total == 0}<p>No Events</p>{/if}` conditional.

Also, it goes without saying that we recommend updating EE and Calendar at some point. Both versions are quite old. (**Make database and file backups before you do**)